# 23.10 Error message every boot ACPI Bios error (bug): Failure creating named object

Tags: boot, bios, acpi

I also had this same problem when I was using linux mint some time ago. Switched to the newest version ubuntu I could get which was 23.10 at the time, and it keeps persisting. I am on a dual boot with windows 10, and windows never has this error message.

Always every boot for ubuntu this comes up my screen:

```
[0.634279] ACPI Bios error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_sb.PCI0.gPP1.PTXH] , AE_already_exist (20230331/dswload2-326) 
[0.634294] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230331/psobject-220)
```

I am a normal average linux user (gamer) so i am no coding wizard or something like some guys here. So I have no clue what to do. I tried asking AI but he did not know either, he suggested Id update BIOS but am a bit afraid to do so.

AI did tell me I should fix it because it could become worse over time, something about power management he mentioned. And he also suggested I ask the community.

I heard other ppl saying this bug was benign and it was because of the bios being newer than the kernel or something? But I used a fairly new ubuntu version, so not sure that is true in this case.